# Grpc ModuleNotFoundError when called from outside module: No module named 'recommendations_pb2'

Tags: python, grpc, modulenotfounderror

I want to create a grpc project,and the code please check this link: https://gitee.com/wen2204/test/tree/master.
when I run the module recommendations.py, it can be run successfully and no errors come out.
but, when I want to call the module recommendations.py from Main.py by recommendations.serve(). the errors come out:recommendations.py", line 7, in 
from recommendations_pb2 import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'recommendations_pb2'
it's quite strange, it seems that the grpc code can not stay in sub package.otherewise you can not call it.

**Folder structure:**

1. protobufs[**Folder**]
   recommendations.proto
2. recommendations[**Folder**]
   recommendations_pb2_grpc.py
   recommendations_pb2.py
   recommendations.py
3. Main.py

**recommendations.py** **[excute this file is ok]**

```
from concurrent import futures
import random
import time

import grpc

from recommendations_pb2 import (
    BookCategory,
    BookRecommendation,
    RecommendationResponse,
)
import recommendations_pb2_grpc

books_by_category = {
    BookCategory.MYSTERY: [
        BookRecommendation(id=1, title="The Maltese Falcon"),
        BookRecommendation(id=2, title="Murder on the Orient Express"),
        BookRecommendation(id=3, title="The Hound of the Baskervilles"),
    ],
    BookCategory.SCIENCE_FICTION: [
        BookRecommendation(
            id=4, title="The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"
        ),
        BookRecommendation(id=5, title="Ender's Game"),
        BookRecommendation(id=6, title="The Dune Chronicles"),
    ],
    BookCategory.SELF_HELP: [
        BookRecommendation(
            id=7, title="The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People"
        ),
        BookRecommendation(
            id=8, title="How to Win Friends and Influence People"
        ),
        BookRecommendation(id=9, title="Man's Search for Meaning"),
    ],
}

class RecommendationService(
    recommendations_pb2_grpc.RecommendationsServicer
):
    def Recommend(self, request, context):
        if request.category not in books_by_category:
            context.abort(grpc.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, "Category not found")

        books_for_category = books_by_category[request.category]
        num_results = min(request.max_results, len(books_for_category))
        books_to_recommend = random.sample(
            books_for_category, num_results
        )

        return RecommendationResponse(recommendations=books_to_recommend)

def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    recommendations_pb2_grpc.add_RecommendationsServicer_to_server(
        RecommendationService(), server
    )
    server.add_insecure_port("[::]:50051")
    server.start()
    print('The server has started.....................')
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve()
```

**Main.py** [excute from this file will throw errors]

```
import recommendations.recommendations as recommendations
recommendations.serve()
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, currently, I have to keep these files in the same level directory. then there will be no errors.
--directory.recommendations_pb2_grpc.py
--recommendations_pb2.py
--recommendations.py
--Main.py

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).